# Update Route53 record using lambda nodejs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to update a record in Route53 using a lambda function and nodejs runtime.

The problem is I am getting no errors, no logs or anything from route53 to even understand why it is not working.

I have setup the following:

- Lambda function
- SNS to read messages from
- Attached a policy to update/change record sets

My lambda code:

```
console.log('Running updateRecordSet');

/* global HOSTED_ZONE_ID*/
/* global DNS_RECORD_NAME*/

HOSTED_ZONE_ID = 'xxxx';
DNS_RECORD_NAME = 'dns-record.internal.example.com.';

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var route53 = new aws.Route53();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
console.log('SNS message:', message);

try {
  const data = JSON.parse(message);

  if (data.ip) {
      console.log('New IP: ', data.ip);

      var newRecord = {
      HostedZoneId: HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
      ChangeBatch: {
        Changes: [{
          Action: 'UPSERT',
          ResourceRecordSet: {
            Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
            Type: 'A',
            ResourceRecords: [{Value: data.ip}],
            TTL: 30,
          }
        }]
      }
    };

    updateRecordSet(route53, DNS_RECORD_NAME, HOSTED_ZONE_ID, newRecord, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                return context.fail(err);
              }
              return context.succeed('OK');
            });
  }
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}

return message;
};

function updateRecordSet(route53, DNS_RECORD_NAME, HOSTED_ZONE_ID, newRecord, callback) {

console.log("Executing function updateRecordSet");

route53.changeResourceRecordSets(newRecord, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Got an err");
    return callback(err);
  }

  return console.log('Updated A record for', DNS_RECORD_NAME);
});

}
```

I get the output:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: 4ef801ba-c03c-4582-33a8-c078c46f0b03 Version: $LATEST
2019-04-07T04:18:55.201Z    4ef801ba-c03c-4582-83a8-c078c46f0b03    SNS message: {"ip": "10.1.1.1"}
2019-04-07T04:18:55.201Z    4ef801ba-c03c-4582-83a8-c078c46f0b03    New IP:  10.1.1.1
2019-04-07T04:18:55.201Z    4ef801ba-c03c-4582-83a8-c078c46f0b03    Executing function updateRecordSet
END RequestId: 4ef801ba-c03c-4582-33a8-c078c46f0b03
```

If the IAM policy is wrong I would at least get some kind of authentication error?

Answer (score 1):

I could not get async to work with lambda for some reason but finally got working code.

This lambda will update or insert a record set in Route53 reading from SNS with a JSON message like `{"ip": "10.1.1.1"}`

```
console.log('Running updateRecordSet');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

/* global HOSTED_ZONE_ID*/
/* global DNS_RECORD_NAME*/

HOSTED_ZONE_ID = 'xxxxxx';
DNS_RECORD_NAME = 'dns-record.example.com.';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

  var route53 = new AWS.Route53();

  // Get message from SNS
  var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
  const data = JSON.parse(message);

  if (typeof data.ip !== "undefined") {
    route53.changeResourceRecordSets({
      HostedZoneId : HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
      ChangeBatch : {
          Changes : [{
              Action: 'UPSERT',
              ResourceRecordSet: {
                  Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
                  Type: 'A',
                  ResourceRecords: [
                      {
                          Value: data.ip
                      }
                  ],
                  TTL: 30
              }
          }]
      }
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        else {
            console.log('Updated Route53 DNS record ' + DNS_RECORD_NAME);
        }
    });

  } else {
    console.log('No IP found in message. Discarding.');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have full promise and await thing setup, you can try the below code. It has a few additional things like STS assume-role for cross-account ROUTE53 access. Additionally, it has a weighted logic to create multiple CNAMEs. I understand this does not fit your use case, however it may help somebody who stumbles upon a similar issue to create Weighted load balancing with CNAME.

```js
console.log('Running route53 changeRecrodSet with CNAME');

/* global HOSTED_ZONE_ID*/
/* global DNS_RECORD_NAME*/

const HOSTED_ZONE_ID = "xxxx";
const DNS_RECORD_NAME = "xxxxxx.com";

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-1';

async function update_recordset(route53, records){
  return route53.changeResourceRecordSets(records).promise();
}

async function getcred(){
  console.log("inside getcred");
  var sts = new AWS.STS();
  try {
    let temp_cred = sts.assumeRole({
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx',
      RoleSessionName: 'awssdk'
    }).promise();
    console.log("TEMP",temp_cred);
    return temp_cred;
  }catch(err){
    console.log("ERROR",err);
  }
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
  console.log('SNS message:', message);
  try{
    const data = JSON.parse(message);

  if (data.cname) {
      console.log('New IP: ', data.cname);
    const sts_result = await getcred();
  console.log("STS_RESULT", sts_result);
  AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: sts_result.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: sts_result.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: sts_result.Credentials.SessionToken
  });
  var route53 = new AWS.Route53();
  console.log("ROUTE53 RESULT",route53);
  const newRecord = {
        HostedZoneId: HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
        ChangeBatch: {
          Changes: [
            {
              Action: 'UPSERT',
              ResourceRecordSet: {
                SetIdentifier: "elb",
                Weight: 100,
                Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
                Type: 'CNAME',
                ResourceRecords: [{ Value: "xxxxx.sxxxxx.com" }],
                TTL: 300,
              },
            },
            {
              Action: 'UPSERT',
              ResourceRecordSet: {
                SetIdentifier: "cflare",
                Weight: 100,
                Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
                Type: 'CNAME',
                ResourceRecords: [{ Value: data.cname }],
                TTL: 300,
              },
            }],
        },
      };
    const results = await update_recordset(route53,newRecord); 
    console.log("Result", results);
  }
  }catch(err){
    console.log("ERR",err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either put an **async - await** or just **callback()**. Both it is a bad practice.
I would do something like this:

```
console.log('Running updateRecordSet');

/* global HOSTED_ZONE_ID*/
/* global DNS_RECORD_NAME*/

HOSTED_ZONE_ID = 'xxxx';
DNS_RECORD_NAME = 'dns-record.internal.example.com.';

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var route53 = new aws.Route53();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
console.log('SNS message:', message);

try {
  const data = JSON.parse(message);

  if (data.ip) {
      console.log('New IP: ', data.ip);

      var newRecord = {
      HostedZoneId: HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
      ChangeBatch: {
        Changes: [{
          Action: 'UPSERT',
          ResourceRecordSet: {
            Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
            Type: 'A',
            ResourceRecords: [{Value: data.ip}],
            TTL: 30,
          }
        }]
      }
    };

   let result = await route53.changeResourceRecordSets(newRecord);
   console.log(result);

  }
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}

return message;
};
```

Also you are right about the iam role, you will get an autherization error if your code runs all the functions correctly.

Comment: I didnt had the privelege to test it, so it may have some syntax errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That at least returns a big message back. But it still refuses to update the record. The message also doesn't really say anything, but seems to just be a big object with no error message.

Comment: In this case the changeResourceRecordSets() runs but probably it gets a timeout or some error that doesnt have to do with the code. If you go to CloudWatch and look at the full message you will see at the end a brief message of the error or something. If you want post it so we can solve it together . :)

Answer (score 0):

To get `async`/`await` to work with AWS sdk, you need `promisify`.
See example below...

```js
console.log('Running updateRecordSet');

/* global HOSTED_ZONE_ID*/
/* global DNS_RECORD_NAME*/

HOSTED_ZONE_ID = 'xxxx';
DNS_RECORD_NAME = 'dns-record.internal.example.com.';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const route53 = new aws.Route53();
const { promisify } = require('util');

const changeResourceRecordSets = promisify(route53.changeResourceRecordSets.bind(route53));
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
  console.log('SNS message:', message);

  try {
    const data = JSON.parse(message);

    if (data.ip) {
      console.log('New IP: ', data.ip);

      const newRecord = {
        HostedZoneId: HOSTED_ZONE_ID,
        ChangeBatch: {
          Changes: [
            {
              Action: 'UPSERT',
              ResourceRecordSet: {
                Name: DNS_RECORD_NAME,
                Type: 'A',
                ResourceRecords: [{ Value: data.ip }],
                TTL: 30,
              },
            }],
        },
      };

      const results = await changeResourceRecordSets(newRecord);
      if (results.ChangeInfo.Status === 'PENDING') {
        console.log('Updated A record for', DNS_RECORD_NAME, results);
        return {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: 'Success',
        };
      } else {
        console.error(results);
        return {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: 'Something went wrong',
        };
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```